# Actual parameters in Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I'm confused about actual parameters in Java. Since it's just parameters, I assume that literals, constants,variables, expressions can be actual parameters during function calling.

But I'm confused about a function call. Is it possible to have a function call being an actual parameter in Java?

Comment: No. It is not possible to pass functions as first class citizens. However, the _result_ of a function can be; for example `foo(bar())` - `bar()` will be called and the result of that function will be passed as an argument to `foo()`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider so in other words, in any circumstances, a function call can never be part of an actual parameter? Aside from the example you gave.

Comment: Add a code example of what you are trying to do. "_Aside from the example you gave_" - what are you envisaging?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm not coding at the moment, just trying to grasp on what can be parameters in java.

Comment: @clink look at the possible duplicate. I think this (plus some research) will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "are functions first-class citizens in Java, as they are in C" then the question is "no, not really".

But with Java 8's lambdas, you can get pretty close:

```
import java.util.function.IntFunction;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final IntFunction square = x -> x * x;
        printFunctionResult(square, 2);
    }

    public static void printFunctionResult(final IntFunction function, final int value) {
        System.out.println(function.apply(value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Java 8 lambdas are syntactic sugar for anonymous classes - nothing more.

Comment: Not quite, there are some profound differences between the two. And I think that my answer points out very clearly that a function (or method, to use the Java parlance) is not a first-class citizens, like objects and primitives are.